# ActiveX Control in C#  - results in error in IE8

Tags: c#, .net, activex, cab

I followed the following steps to create a ActiveX control:

```
- Create a new Class Library project in Visual Studio
- Create a new class that inherits from UserControl
- Create a new interface that exposes the controls methods and properties to COM interop
- Make the control class implement the new interface
- Mark the control as safe for scripting and initialization
- Create a .msi installer for the control
- Package the control in a .cab file for web deployment
- Ininitalize and test the control with JavaScript
```

(found at this [article](http://www.olavaukan.com/2010/08/creating-an-activex-control-in-net-using-c/))

When I run the test in IE i get the following error:
"windows has blocked this software because it can't verify the publisher ie8"

Could anyone give me some advice on what direction i should go in to find what i missed in doing this?

Am i supposed to register the cab? (i didn't)

I am restricted to working in .net 3.5 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options:

1. Sign the CAB
2. Add your site to trusted site or change your browser settings

Here some links about signing the CAB:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(v=vs.85).aspx - Signing and Checking Code with Authenticode
2. http://www.top20toolbar.com/misc/codesigncert.htm - Article about how to sign ActiveX for free

you can also try to install the activeX with non-admin rights (Only for vista and Windows 7)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369519(v=vs.85).aspx - Installing a Package with Elevated Privileges for a Non-Admin

Comment: Thank you for the responses I will try them and let you know how it goes (I am sorry for the delay was on another project for a bit)

Comment: @acolene Are you still on another project?